# login phpMyAdmin to MySql getting error in Ubuntu 18.04 kubernetes nodes

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, kubernetes

i am trying to install phpMyAdmin and Mysql as pods in my Kubernetes cluster.
everything is okay but when i try to log in into mysql by browser from phpMyAdmin interface i failed 
the error massages are:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

with root username and test password // inside secret file

for mysql deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.6
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-credentials
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          name: mysql-volume-mount
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-volume-mount
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-volume
```

for phpMyAdmin deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin
  labels:
    app: phpmyadmin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: PMA_HOST
          value: mysql
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

for secret file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-credentials
type: Opaque
data:
   password: ZGVtbw==
```

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:27:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-5678c6dfb4-45ltq                   1/1     Running   0          29m
phpmyadmin-deployment-86687f7558-hq2jh   1/1     Running   0          34m
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `PMA_HOST=mysql` as an environment variable on your PHPMyAdmin deployment, so make sure to have a service using this name, and use the proper [selectors to match](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) the MySQL deployment.

For example, apply the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mysql
```

Then you can log in using the following credentials (as per your secret):

> User: root
>   Pass: demo